# Get "date" to understand a timestamp phrase of a different language

Tags: bash, date, locale, timestamps

My web-scraping scripts have long enjoyed using `date -d` to read in human-formatted time and date stamps like "March 11, 1999" and convert to any other format I need via the -s parameter.

How might I get it to understand dates printed in other locales like `27 Kwi, 13:54` in [Polish](http://stooq.pl/notowania/?data=&kat=g2)?  I can artifically prepend/append the year (2012) if needed.

I checked my `env` and tried the following, but no luck:

```
LOCALE=PL date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
LANGUAGE=pl_PL:pl date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL:pl date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
LANG=pl_PL:pl date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
LC_COLLATE=pl_PL:pl date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL:pl date -d "30 Kwi, 17:02"
date: invalid date `30 Kwi, 17:02'
```

In my system as installed,

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Reminder: I don't get to control the input format.  But I may prepend or append eg. the current year before sending off the whole string to a universal, magic parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

[GNU coreutils - General date syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#General-date-syntax)

> In the current implementation, only English is supported for words and abbreviations like ‘AM’, ‘DST’, ‘EST’, ‘first’, ‘January’, ‘Sunday’, ‘tomorrow’, and ‘year’.

---

Since I can't find a way to do it using `date` or any other tool like it, here's how you could do it in Python.

```
import time
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pl_PL')

logtime = time.strptime('30 Kwi 2012, 17:02', '%d %b %Y, %H:%M')
```

You could use strptime in any language that provides it, e.g. [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~gozer/POSIX-strptime-0.05/lib/POSIX/strptime.pm), [C](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), etc.

---

If you really have to use only `bash`, try this:

```
# create an associative array, e.g. month[kwi] = 4
# requires bash >= 4
declare -A month
for m in {1..12}; do
  # any year should do since we only print the month
  mmm=$(LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8 date -d "2000-$m-1" "+%b")
  month[$mmm]=$m
done

# test that the associative array works, should print 4
echo ${month[kwi]}

# given arguments <day> <month> <year>, <hour>:<minute>
# where month is a three-letter abbreviated Polish month name
# print it using the system's default date format
pl_date() {
  local d=$1
  local mmm=$2
  local yyyy=$3
  local hhmm=$4

  local m=${month[$mmm]}
  date -d "$yyyy-$m-$d $hhmm"
}

# use without quotes
pl_date 30 kwi 2012 17:02
```

---

Notes:

Even in English, the year is required and the comma is not allowed:

```
$ date -d "30 Apr, 17:02"
date: invalid date `30 Apr, 17:02'

$ date -d "30 Apr 2012 17:02"
Mon Apr 30 17:02:00 PDT 2012
```

Only `LANGUAGE` supports a list like `pl_PL:pl`, the other variables require a single name, e.g. `pl_PL` or `pl_PL.UTF-8`.

Comment: Very good demonstration of `bash` techniques. Besides that I mostly use `Ruby` for programs if not `awk` for one-liners, both have `strptime` or similar--where you still have to specify the field format manually.

Comment: GNU `awk` has `strftime` but no `strptime` as far as I can tell.

Comment: And yes, Ruby is another good choice, but if you need to use Ruby, Python, or Perl, it might be better to write the whole script in that language.